# php can't find file after cache clear

Tags: php, symfony

This is so bizarre... I'm using Symfony 2.8. My login page was showing normally. I clear the cache:

```
php app/console cache:clear
```

And now `twig` can't find the `login.html.twig` anymore, which I haven't moved!

```
Warning: file_get_contents(/Users/nacho/Documents/Symfony/docker-symfony/symfony/
vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/Resources/views/Security/login.html.twig):
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I am sure the path is correct: I haven't moved the file and the paths are identical.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory) great answer, but it doesn't seem to apply to my situation. Any ideas?

Comment: You tried asset install after that

Comment: I had something similar, try to remove vendor directory and update with "composer update"

Comment: ShayAltman answer will correct your error, but it should not be deleted after a cache clear ...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try when I get back to work.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. No need to remove the vendor folder though ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem today. "composer update" did it for me.